# Django: call method after clicking button

Tags: python, django

I was searching for this answer but none met my expectation. So, In my template I have some content and wanted to add button (which later will add to favorites). After clicking I want to call method from my *views.py* and redirect to other view.

my *views.py*

```
def home(request):
    //logic here
    request.session['url'] = url
    return render(request,'file.html')

def function_to_call(request):
    ///logic here
    url = request.session.get('url')
    return render(request,'second_file.html',url=url)
```

*file.html*

```
<form action="{% url 'function_to_call' %}">
    <button id="submit" type="button" value="Click" />
</form>
```

and in my *urls.py*

```
url(r'^function_to_call/',views.function_to_call,name='function_to_call'),
```

Unfortunately, after clicking on button, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you are submitting a form, you should use

```
 <a href="{% url 'function_to_call' %}">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need to use a POST request rather than a GET this will work:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'function_to_call' %}">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

Using a post can be helpful when you don't want to include data in the querystring because it's a little less secure than having the parameters in the request's body.